# Grep lines that match pattern twice

Tags: shell, text-processing, grep, search

Usually `grep` outputs any lines that match a pattern.  I want to be able to find lines that match the pattern multiple times.  For example, if my search pattern was "foo", then:

```bsh
foo bar      # Would not be matched
foo foo bar  # Would be matched
bar foofoo   # Would be matched
foobarfoo    # Would be matched
```

Is there a way I can tell `grep` to find only lines that contain multiple matches of my search pattern?

Comment: Everything I read when I was looking this up was explaining how to use multiple patterns at the same time.  I guess I just am looking up the wrong terms...

Comment: `grep` has no such option. `grep "${pattern}.*${pattern}"` does what you want, though.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I didn't think about putting it all in one pattern!  That makes perfect sense.  Do you want to make that an answer?

Comment: If the pattern is `bob`, would you say it  matches twice on `bobob`? In another words, are the matches required to be disjoint or not?

Comment: Same for `<.*>` on an input like `<a<b>c>` where you could say there's only one or there are 4 matches (`<a<b>`, `<a<b>c>`, `<b>`, `<b>c>`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
grep -E "(foo.*){2}" file
```

This matches at least 2 times on each line of file or output, you can give minimum number of matches.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to match all lines that matches *any* string twice:

```
grep '\(.\{1,\}\).*\1'
```

You can change the length to match by changing `1,`:

```
seq 10000 | grep '\(.\{2,\}\).*\1'
```

This uses Basic Regular Expression ([BRE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html)) and should therefore work on any POSIX compliant `grep`.

If you convert the regexp to use non-greedy regexp (not supported everywhere) it does not seem to speed up matching:

```
grep -E '(..*?).*?\1'
```

The graph shows runtime in seconds of runs with and without non-greedy on 100 lines of each n numbers (~ line length).

```
greedy() {
  a=`seq $1`;
  yes $a | head -n 100 | grep '\(.\{1,\}\).*\1' | LC_ALL=C wc;
}
nongreedy() {
  a=`seq $1`;
  yes $a | head -n 100 | grep -E '(..*?).*?\1' | LC_ALL=C wc;
}
export -f greedy
export -f nongreedy
parallel --jl my.log {2} {1}000 {2} ::: {1..100} ::: greedy nongreedy
```

[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110155/discussion-between-isaac-and-ole-tange).

Answer (score 1):

```
grep "foo.*foo" file.txt
```

That will only return lines where `foo` appears two or more times. It won't return lines where it only appears once.

The above will work without quotes most of the time but in other cases where there are filenames in the directory that match the glob such as `foo.barfoo`, for example, it is necessary to quote the regex which is why I have edited my answer to include double quotes.

Comment: You must quote the regex. Otherwise very unpleasant things can happen.

Comment: @HaukeLaging That depends on the context. In this case, it works whether it is quoted or not. Whitespace and special characters aren't an issue here.

Comment: @NasirRiley Yes, it works just fine in this case, but other people who stumble across this question might be in a scenario where it would cause an issue...

Comment: @Questionmark Then I'll put a note into my answer to account for it.

Comment: @NasirRiley, the unquoted version falls apart the moment someone has files that happen to match it as a filename. Or if you run zsh, since it complains about unmatched globs by default (`zsh: no matches found: foo.*foo`). And that's a _good_ feature. Better to just quote anything that looks like a glob if it isn't meant as one.

Comment: No, it must be quoted because `*` is a special character in the shell. `foo.*foo` will be expanded by the shell to the list of filenames in the current directory that start with `foo.` and end in `foo` and if there's no matching file, it will either trigger an error (`csh`, `tcsh`, `zsh`, `fish`, `bash -O failglob`) or expand to nothing (older fish, `zsh -o nullglob`, `bash -O nullglob`) or be left as-is.

Comment: @ilkkachu I have put a note in the answer to account for this. The first one without the quotes works if what you mentioned isn't true and the second will work otherwise. If the first doesn't work, then one can simply use the second one. Everything is accounted for. It is better to just quote it as that works either way, but it's not the end of the world if it's not quoted. Worst case, it just wouldn't work so one can just use the quotes. The thing is, I have created a file in the directory where I'm running the command to test called `foobarfoo` and I can't produce what you have mentioned.

Comment: @NasirRiley, `foobarfoo` doesn't match that as a glob, `foo.barfoo` would. (the shell's filename patterns are not the same as regexes.) And if it existed with no other files matching the glob, grep would get the filename as the pattern, instead of the intended one. It could cause a silent failure to find you're looking for. The case with more than one file matching the pattern would be similar, except that now grep would look for the the first filename in all of the files. i.e. `grep foo.*foo file.txt` would expand to `grep foo.afoo foo.bfoo file.txt` with no error.

Comment: @ilkkachu Okay, that second filename does produce what you are talking about. I have updated the answer to account for this so that it's clear as to what the difference is between when the regex is quoted and not quoted. That's useful for others to know.